# While using capture-website, puppeteer with webpack throwing error:browser not downloaded, at ChromeLauncher.launch (webpack-internal)

Tags: node.js, angular, puppeteer

I am trying to take screenshot by providing html file on node js.
I have used capture-website package.
Here is the code:

```
try{
await captureWebsite.file('file.html', 'file.png', {overwrite: true}, function (error) {
                    if (error) {
                       console.log('error',error);
                    }
                });
}catch(e){
console.log('error in capture image:',  e)
}
```

Version: 
node:12.16.1
capture-website: "0.8.1"
Angular : 7

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```js
    async function screenshotFromHtml ({ html, timeout = 2000 }: ScreenshotOptions) {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
          headless: !process.env.DEBUG_HEADFULL,
          args: [
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
          ]
        })

        const page = await browser.newPage()

        // Set viewport to something big
        // Prevents Carbon from cutting off lines
        await page.setViewport({
          width: 2560,
          height: 1080,
          deviceScaleFactor: 2
        })

        page.setContent(html)

        const base64 = await page.screenshot({ encoding: "base64" }) as string;

        // Wait some more as `waitUntil: 'load'` or `waitUntil: 'networkidle0'
        await page.waitFor(timeout)
        // Close browser
        await browser.close()

        return base64
    }
```

This code is in typescript, but you can use the function body in your JS project

In [this github file](https://github.com/chegaai/ms-certificate/blob/master/src/utils/HTML.ts) you can  see a html render code too

Comment: How do you start the Angular/Puppeteer application? All the examples I see start the application with `ng test app` but I don't want to test it, I want to use it to generate PDFs/images at server side.

Comment: you can use the code above in server-side apps. You may create an Express nodejs app and use it